# Assigning array data to a model properties in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am working on a method to activate new members. I get the following error:

Undefined offset: 1

The error occurs on the line which contains the following:

$model->username=$data[1];

Is there a Yii way to make this work better?

I am a rookie with php, oop, and Yii, so any assistance would be appreciated greatly!

The method basically takes a get request from a user. The get runs this method and contains a key which is used to validate their account. Validations are stored in a file with the same name as the key. Inside the file is a pipe delimited line that contains the date, username, email, salt, and a password hash. After reading the file, and exploding the data at the pipe, I need to assign the data to the model, and then it will be saved to the db.

```
...

        $model=new Users;

        $model->activation_key=$_GET['key'];

        $path_to_validation_files = Yii::app()->basePath."/data/new_member_validations";
        $validation_file = $path_to_validation_files . "/".$model->activation_key.".dat";

        if(is_readable($validation_file) && !empty($validation_file))
        {
            if($fp = fopen($validation_file, 'r'))
            {
                while(!feof($fp))
                {
                    $line = fread($fp, filesize($validation_file));
                }
                fclose($fp);
                $data = explode('|', $line);

                if(!empty($data)){
                    $model->username=$data[1];
                    $model->email=$data[2];
                    $model->salt=$data[3];
                    $model->password=$data[4];
                } else {
                    throw new CHttpException(500,'Validation file contained no data.');
                }

            } else {
                throw new CHttpException(500,'Cannot open validation file.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(404,'Validation file not found, not readable, or empty.');
        }


...
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually getting the line from the file in $line? You can check that with if (empty($line)) die('not getting line') after fclose($fp); .. This is just to make sure, as there seems to be a problem with $line. Also the while loop is redundant as fread will read as many bytes as you have specified i.e. the whole file.

Comment: what's the output of `print_r($data)`? Are you sure there is always something in the second array position?

Comment: @ldg - print_r is Array ( [0] => ) which explains the error, but why is it blank is the other issue :)

Comment: @Abhijit - I took out the while loop and it now works, at least that part is working ...now it won't save the model ...hopefully I can figure that out. Do you need do something before model->save()?

Comment: @Abhijit - I did a model->save(false) so it wouldn't try and validate and now it saves. On to the next step :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `attributes` property of the `CActiveRecord` class to load an associative array.

For example, say you have a model with properties `foo` and `bar`, and you have an array `data('foo'=>1, 'bar'=2)`

you can set `$myModel->attributes = data`, and it will loop through the array and assign the properties to the model (but only if those attributes have **validation** rules)

Comment: +1, thanks. Wish you could just do $model = new MyModel($dataArray);

Comment: I believe this doesn't seem to work if, instead of an array, you have an array of arrays though.

Comment: I was just wondering how Yii performs this! specifically in Yii2, `$model->attributes = $_POST['Formname']` would fill the corresponding model attributes with data? Do you know what goes on behind the scene? I mean how does all data in array gets loaded into the corresponding attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem especially when using an array of array. This is how i solved it.

```
public function epidemicSelectInsertParticipant($class){
    $data=  Participant::findAll(['class'=>$class]);
    if($data){
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $model = new Epidemicparticipant;
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                if($key=='id'){

                }else{
                        $model->$key = $val;
                }
            }
           $model->save(false);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }  else {
      return false;  
    }
}
```

In my case,`$data` is a multi-dimensional array.They keys($key)of `$value` are the same as `$model->attributes`.